# Find reverse percentage

Tags: math

I have a function that sets a bootstrap progress bar based on a number it finds in a div .days-due. It works fine but the progress bar is opposite width that I want.

How can I reverse the progBarValue number?

```
function daysUntil(year, month, day) {
  var now = new Date(),
      dateEnd = new Date(year, month - 1, day), // months are zero-based
      days = (dateEnd - now) / 1000/60/60/24;   // convert milliseconds to days

  return Math.round(days);
}

// find percentage to due date
$('#paging1 ul li').each(function () {

    var monthDue = $(this).find('.month').text();
    var dayDue = $(this).find('.day').text();
    var yearDue = $(this).find('.year').text();

    $(this).find('.days-due').text(daysUntil(yearDue, monthDue, dayDue));

    // progress bar
    // find number of days until due date
    var progBarValue = $(this).find('.days-due').text();
    // limit days due to no more than 100%
    progBarValue = progBarValue > 100 ? 100 : progBarValue;
    // set progress bar width
    $(this).find('.bar').width(progBarValue +"%");

});
```

Comment: Subtract your current percentage from 100. IE, if you're 10% done, you're 90% not done. That's what *percent* means. This is a math question, not a programming question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Um, `$(this).find('.bar').width((100 - progBarValue) +"%");` ?